# Yii2 overiding user/login for backend

Tags: yii2, yii2-user, yii2-advanced-app

I am using yii2-user module on top of the standard Yii2 advanced demo.

Yii2-user provides it's own login function at /user/security/login and linking directly to that works perfectly.

However the advanced demo overides that and directs the call to /user/login probably using the internal routes but I cant track down where that is happening.

I need to tell my Yii2 site not to chip in its own login ( which I have deleted ) and to retain the route to /user/security/login.

config file is directing user to the dektrium yii2-user module and it all seems to be working, it's just the default action into the backend page that reroutes to user/login when a visitor is a guest instead of a registered admin.

Comment: I think you should post some related code. so answer-er can get clear idea

Answer (score 0):

Backend has its own configuration, you should simply modify user component `loginUrl` in **`backend/config/main.php`** .

Comment: dektrium user module does not support 'loginUrl', trying to set it in the user module part of the config throws an exception.

Comment: >'components' => [
>    ..........
>    'user' => [
>             'loginUrl' => 'user/security/login'
>           ],
>   ........  makes no difference, the user/login is still returned

Comment: Also tried overiding it in the SiteController of the backend ..... still insists on going to user/login

Answer (score 0):

Inside your backend **config.php** add one more component

```
    'user' => [
        'loginUrl' => ['user/security/login'],
    ],
```

It helps me out in frontend